# C# MVC Link-To-Sql passing table name and field name to function

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

I am writing an ASP.NET MVC (C#, SQL Server) web site and would like to write a function in my controller in which I pass a table name, a column name, and a value to check against the passed in column name in the passed in table.

If the record is found, I want to return the primary key of the record.

If the value is not found in the table, I want to create it and then return the primary key of that record.

```
private int FindRecord(string tableName, string FieldToCheck, string LookupValue)
{
   /* 1) How do I set the string 'tableName' to a table in my context */

   /* How do I set the string FieldToCheck to a field in the 'tableName' */

   /* How do I return the primary key if LookupValue is in 'FieldToCheck' */

   /* How do I add a record and return primary key if it is now */

   return PrimaryKeyOfFoundOrNewRecord;
}
```

I almost cannot imagine that this question is not a duplicate but I cannot find any examples - perhaps I'm not using the proper terms to search. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Not 100% sure what you are trying to do here, but this probably isn't the best design.  What is the purpose of the function?

Comment: You very well may be right that it's not the best design.
I'm trying to keep my database 3rd normal. For each location I add, I want to store the city, state and country in separate tables. When a user adds a location, I want to check the "country" table to see if the country has already been added. The same with state and city. My thought was to write this function to check those tables before adding the location to the "location" table. Am I way off base? I'm an old programmer just getting used to MVC and object oriented stuff! Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: OK, I see. Yes you should check and associate them to existing records, but you shouldn't write 'one function to rule them all' like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, based on the comment clarification of what is required, then what you might want is something like this:

```
void CreateLocation(string city,string state, string country)
{
   var newLoc = new Location();

   newLoc.City = GetCity(city);

   if (newLoc.City == null)
   {
      newLoc.City = new City() { Name = city });
   }

   //Repeaat this for state and country.

  _context.Locations.Add(newLoc);

  _context.SaveChanges();

}

City GetCity(string city)
{
   var city = from c in _context.Cities
              where c.name.Equals(city)
              select c;

   return city.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Apologies if the syntax is a little off, nearly quitting time here.

---

Sorry, some of this syntax might be entity framework as opposed to linq-to-sql - just noticed your tag.  Syntax is different (marginally) but idea is the same.

Comment: Thank you so very much! I think this is a strategy that will work for me!!